# Solr Custom Boosting if a specific field matches the query

Tags: solr

We are trying to implement a very interesting search logic with custom boosting and I am wondering if Solr can support this.
We have the following fields in our index:

- Name
- Description
- Keywords (array)

Each keyword will have an amount(int value) paired to it.

A search is run across Name, description and keywords field. If a keyword matches the search text, the corresponding index must be boosted based on the amount of the matching keyword only.

I've read through Solr DisMax and they can only boost a field using a fixed amount.

My scenario will be to boost the result by X amount based on matching keywords only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Function queries : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery achieve part of what you are trying to do. The problem is that you want the boost to be set according to a matched part of a field instead of a field . Is the variance in keywords that great? If so

Comment: There will be variance on the keywords as it will be a user supplied value. I'm wondering how we can store the keyword with their corresponding amount in the index as I don't see Solr supporting 2 dimensional arrays from what I've read so far. Thanks for your reply @omu_negru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable solution i see to this problem (assuming ofcourse you DO NOT know the number of keywords in advance) would be to just make the query as a filter query (to skip the scoring stage), get all documents matching ( a bit problematic), then just sort them on your side using the matched term to build the a java Comparator.

Problems may arise when you get a particularly large number of documents, but you could probably side step this issue by pagination

Comment: Your answer got me thinking of dynamically constructing my boost query by doing an initial query to explicitly fetch keywords that would match my query text. Based upon my initial query result, I can iterate through the keywords to construct my boost query such as "bq=keyword:matchkeyword1^amt1 bq=keyword:matchkeyword2^amt2 ..."

Comment: Seems like multiple bq values is not yet supported [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2798)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too much different amounts maybe you can try this on index-time:

Store "keywords" in different fields(`dynamicfields->boost-*`) based on it's amount:

```
boost-1 = keyword1,keyword4,keyword6 <br/>
boost-10 = keyword2<br/>
boost-100 = keyword5
```

You can search across all your boost fields(edismax), boost every dynamicfield with his amount in your `(e)dismax conf(boost-1^1,boost-10^10,boost-100^100)`.

Comment: since these are user generated keywords i doubt there is a finite set to choose from

Comment: @Roy thanks for your reply, dynamic field based on amount sounds like a winner but if only we have a finite set